# Android 5.1.1 broke photo selection

Tags: android

Pretty simple really:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); - Tried this too
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_IMAGE); // 1
```

Used to work fine, doesn't anymore. On the left side hamburger button, select `Photos` as the source. You get a new screen showing 'Photos' which you can click on as well as other folders on your device ('Pictures', 'Screenshots', etc). Click Photos at this point. You'll get a spinner that never stops.

This worked fine until the 5.1.1 update. Can anyone confirm? Any workaround anyone has found?

**[Edit]** - I submitted a bug to Android [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182376). Will post a workaround if I can.

[image: Issue pictured]

Comment: I doubt that there is a programming solution, unless you're the author of the Photos app. Your symptoms would indicate that the Photos app has a bug, and there's not a whole lot you can really do about that.

Comment: Yeah probably not. Was thinking maybe someone would point out a difference in API in 5.1.1 and I'd have to update my code for some deprecated method.

Comment: Submit a bug report :|